# python - selenium auto fill web forms

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I searched the internet but I couldn't find the exact answer. I have a form and information to fill. Reading information from data.csv file. But no matter what I did, the form starts from the last line of the csv file. how can i fix this? Here are the codes below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import csv
import time


with open('sample.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    row1 = next(csv_reader)

    for line in csv_reader:
       driver_path = ".../chromedriver.exe"
       brave_path = ".../brave.exe"

s=Service(driver_path)
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.binary_location = brave_path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=option)
driver.get("www.xxxxx.com")

time.sleep(1)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/a")).click();

name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/form/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/input"))
name.send_keys(line[0])


age = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/form/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/input"))
age.send_keys(line[1])

score = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/form/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/input"))
score.send_keys(line[2])
```

Comment: I think the code is incorrectly indente. (you need to have all code inside the loop ), actually first complete the loop and next fill the form with the last value of "line"

Comment: No dude, it didn't check and it's still reading the last line.

Comment: I have tested by formatting the code and using demo data, it works correctly line by line from the beginning of the CSV, see this code https://pastebin.com/raw/CeNw0Ze1